# How to make some pages not directly accessible from browser?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, html

ex: I have two file in my web app : 1] index.html 2] some.html (or jsp)

From browser only index.html is to be accessible,

So If I call localhost:8080/index.html, it should return the actual page, and on load If I direct (Redirect) to some.html then some.html page should show up,

If I directly call localhost:8080/some.html, it should throw out an error that the page cannot be directly accessible, is there a way I can achieve this if I host the webapp in tomcat server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution is to move them under the WEB-INF directory. From here they are not publicly accessible but you can have a Servlet or some other controller forward to them

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/configurewebapp.htm#WBAPP158

> The WEB-INF directory is not part of the public document tree of the
>   application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory can be served
>   directly to a client by the container. **However, the contents of the
>   WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource
>   and getResourceAsStream() method calls on the ServletContext or
>   includes/forwards using the RequestDispatcher**.

An alternative is to leave them outside of WEB-INF and configure a security constraint in your web.xml. For eaxmple, if you have them in {webapp-root}/pages:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP Files</web-resource-name>
        <description>No direct access to JSP files</description>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>No direct browser access to JSP files</description>
        <role-name>NobodyHasThisRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Filters` and deny access to `jsp's`.

```
public class FilterMyJsp implements Filter{
    public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletReponse response,                
       FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletRequest req= (HttpServletRequest) request;
      req.getRequestDispather("HandleError.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
}
```

**Web.xml**
`<filter>
   <filter-name>FilterMyJsp</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.FilterMyJsp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>FilterMyJsp</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`

**URL pattern** `*` will apply this filter to each of the jsp's. You can design the `HandleError.jsp` with your respective error message which will be shown when user tries to access the other page.